# AngularJS Prevent Browser Escaping Characters

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created a directive that highlights code but it seems browsers are modifying that code before I can get to it and highlight it.

Here's what's happening.

I have a directive called `my-compile` which basically just spits the passed value into the element's innerHTML and runs a `$compile` on it.

eg:

```
<span my-compile="details"></span>
```

And details would be something like:

```
here are some details and here's a <code lang="java">first = temp & 0xFF &amp;</code>
```

here's the directive code that matters (this is in the link function):

```
element.html(details); $compile(element.children())(scope);
```

So `$compile` sees the `<code>` directive and hands that off to the code directive, except, and here's the problem, the `<code>` directive does an `element.html()` to get the contents and this is returned:

```
first = temp &amp; 0xFF &amp;
```

The problem is that the code is now wrong, because the first & wasn't escaped.

How can I still use the `<code>` directive in a similar fashion but preserve the & sign (and I assume this happens with > and < signs too)?

My only idea was a lookup service but that's kinda messy, but maybe my only option as the second it hits the browser's DOM it gets escaped, but the escaped & doesn't get double escaped.

I've also tried using `element[0].innerHTML` thinking maybe it's an Angular/jQuery sanitization thing, but it it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you added html to your DOM first time `element.html(details);` browser parses it as html(btw - it fixes incorrect escaping, adds missing close tags, etc), and when your are trying to access it later - you are getting html with all fixes done during parsing.

The only way how you can fix it - properly encode your code content as a text entity(for provided example if you need text `first = temp & 0xFF &amp;` encoded version would be `first = temp &amp; 0xFF &amp;amp;`), an access it as `element.text()` but not as `element.html()` in your `code` directive.

Comment: I ended up just double encoding everything so literal `&amp;` would become `&amp;amp;` which then gets decoded with the `.text()` retrieval. Thanks for the help! :D